# What is going on in this?

Tags: c++, assembly

I am reading through someone's code, and he is calling functions like this.  The "this" in that block is a pointer to a virtual method table, and he is using offsets to call a function in said table.  This is a hack thing in case you are wondering.

```
    __asm
{
    MOV EDI, this
    LEA ECX, [EDI + 0x4]
    MOV EDX, DWORD PTR DS:[ECX]
    CALL [EDX + 0x24]
}
```

He has simpler bits of code that just call "this" + the offset, but I am confused on what is going on in this one.  I can post the vtable dump from Ida if that would help at all.

Comment: Oh yeah, and the function returns a pointer to a struct, if that helps any.

Comment: Can you clarify what "what's going on" means?  Are you asking to have the individual assembly instructions explained?  Or is "individual assembly instructions" the answer you were looking for?

Comment: I just want to know how the author is getting an offset of 0xD4 from this.  Also, what is the "DWORD PTR DS:[ECX]" part doing?  That's pretty much what I am trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like multiple inheritance. In such cases, there are separate vtables for each inherited class interface. So, 2nd and 3rd instructions calculate the start of vtable for specified  inherited class interface. Call is obvious, 24 is just a magic number, a known offset to the function to be called in that inherited class.

Answer (score 0):

`this` in C++ is a keyword that can be used in the scope of an object to denote the object itself.

```
class A{
    private:
        int x;

    void method(){
        this->x = 5;    //"this" is a pointer to the object itself
    }
};
```

In this example, "this" is an `A* const`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I know what "this" is.  I was asking what exactly the author is doing in this code.  He is somehow getting a function that is 0xD4 away from the base address, and I can't figure out how.